# Applying separate `masks` for different strings/sequences in a DNAStringSet object in `Bioconductor

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

How to apply separate `masks` for different strings/sequences in a `DNAStringSet` object in `Bioconductor`?

A mask such as `m1` can be applied to a whole `DNAStringSet`.

```
m1 <- Mask(mask.width=nchar(d), start=c(1,17), end=c(3,20))
```

I would like to use mask `m1`, for first `DNAstring` in `DNAStringSet`, another mask `m2` to 2nd `DNAstring` and so on till mask `mn` to nth `DNAString`.

Right now I am using a loop to first extract `DNAstring`, apply `mask`, then apply hardmask and finally append to new `DNAstringset`.

Is there any easier way to do so without using `injectHardMask` and loosing information.

Similar is the case with multiple alignment objects like  `DNAMultipleAlignment`, where also I would like to use separate `masks` for different strings/sequences.

Comment: this is probably more suited to biostars. But a DNAStringSet is a type of list, so a list of Mask objects should work.

Comment: Maybe you can speed it up with an apply function